# Segmentation Fault is comeing while inserting a node in list on hackerrank platform

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am running a test on hackerrank platform. I have to insert the given data at the tail of the list. 

 Class representation ...

```
class SinglyLinkedListNode {
    public:
        int data;
        SinglyLinkedListNode *next;

        SinglyLinkedListNode(int node_data) {
            this->data = node_data;
            this->next = nullptr;
        }
};
```

This is already embedded in the code editor. I can't change it. 
This is explicitly decalared function, this function is not associated with any class.

```
// function to insert node at the tail of the list. 
SinglyLinkedListNode * insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode * head, int data) {

  SinglyLinkedListNode * nn = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
  // node to traverse the list
  SinglyLinkedListNode * temp = head;

  if (!head)
  {
    head = nn;
    return head;
  } 
  else
  {
    while (temp)
    {
      temp = temp - > next;
    }
    temp - > next = nn;
  }

  return head;
}
```

I am getting **Segmentation Fault.**
**Error (stderr)** message:

```
Reading symbols from Solution...done.
[New LWP 113196]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./Solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  insertNodeAtTail (data=302, head=<optimized out>) at Solution.cpp:70
70         temp->next=nn;
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

As i can see, i am no dereferencing any unallocated memory. 
What is the error?

Comment: Do try and keep your indentation under control. What you've got here is best described as chaotic, there's really no consistency at all.

Comment: `head = ` will not  change the list. `head` is a local copy of the actual head pointer you are passing in. You can change the declaration of the parameter to `SinglyLinkedListNode*&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a debugger always first. In this code, you are watching a pointer insted a next pointer of it.

```cpp
 while(temp->next) {
    temp = temp->next;
  }

  temp->next = nn;
```

This is the corrrect code.

Answer (score 3):

This code walks off the end of your linked list, then dereferences a NULL pointer:

```
  while(temp){
    temp=temp->next;
  }
  temp->next=nn;
```

You're effectively waiting until `temp` is a `nullptr` and only then do you use it. That's problematic.

What you need is to look ahead instead:

```
  while(temp->next) {
    temp = temp->next;
  }

  temp->next = nn;
```